# Returned RealmResult have empty values

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm trying to get query results from realm:

```
RealmResults<Line> results = realm.where(Line.class).lessThan("id",5).findAll();
        Line[] lines = results.toArray(new Line[results.size()]);
        for(int i=0;i<lines.length;i++)
            Log.e("erralert", String.valueOf(lines[i].id) + "-" +  lines[i].text + "-" + lines[i].localId);
```

the results are like:

```
0-null-0
0-null-0
0-null-0
0-null-0
```

But actually, I'm sure that the data in the database are correct and changing query `.less than("id",5)` shows that it has actually found 4 items (those with id less than 5). changing 5 to 10, returns 9 results, but the taken results are always empty.

The following code also have the same result:

```
RealmResults<Line> lines = realm.where(Line.class).lessThan("id",20).findAll();
for(int i=0;i<lines.size();i++)
    Log.e("erralert", String.valueOf(lines.get(i).id) + "-" +  lines.get(i).text + "-" + lines.get(i).localId);
```

P.S.: `id` field is Primary Key, so obviously we can't have records like that.

Comment: What's your Realm version?

Comment: What version of Realm are you using?

Comment: My realm version is 5.30

Comment: Did you do a clean rebuild after upgrading?

Comment: its a new project started with realm 5.30. i havent upgraded it.

Comment: If you try with Realm 5.1.0 and it works, then @ChristianMelchior will be very sad (also if your project is small enough and you can send it over to help[at]realm.io so they can reproduce what you are experiencing then that'd be really swell)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce It DID WORK. You are my hero. I wasted 3 days, just changed the version to 5.1.0 and it worked perfectly.

Comment: This is a big problem so I have reported it at https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/6041

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thanks a lot

Comment: Oh yeah one more thing I am curious about just for sake of data. If you use getters/setters outside of class instead of direct field access, does it still fail?